# Let's get critical: Nov 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Open Data Stack Exchange](http://opendata.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How to get wikipedia daily updates](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1142/how-to-get-wikipedia-daily-updates)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Frequency Analysis Character Distribution Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1135/frequency-analysis-character-distribution-data)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Is there a tool to convert geoRSS into geoJSON?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/is-there-a-tool-to-convert-georss-into-geojson)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [A Python guide for open data file formats](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1208/a-python-guide-for-open-data-file-formats)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Stemming of long English text](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1158/stemming-of-long-english-text)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Creative commons licensed audio files of basic French vocabulary](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1186/creative-commons-licensed-audio-files-of-basic-french-vocabulary)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Where can I find normalized data on governmental spending on science?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1172/where-can-i-find-normalized-data-on-governmental-spending-on-science)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1180/how-can-i-query-a-genetics-database-of-snps-preferably-with-r

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [From an entrepreneur's perspective, are there reasons to open data?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1179/from-an-entrepreneurs-perspective-are-there-reasons-to-open-data)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What is a good editor for linked data?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/what-is-a-good-editor-for-linked-data)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---